# What's an idiom/word for "complaining despite having it good"?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I am writing a blog post where I complain about something others may see as a favorable situation: I am getting too many unannounced phone calls with job offers. They come during work hours and interrupt my concentration, though.

So, in my post, I am asking recruiters to shoot me an e-mail first. I am trying to be polite there, so I'd like to say a more elegant version of "I know I'm complaining despite having it good, but..."

I have heard the term "First World Problems" in this context, but that don't fit exactly here.

What's a nice word or idiom to describe this situation?

Comment: *kvetch*.........

Comment: "an embarrassment of riches"?

Comment: Oh thank you! An embarrassment of riches is exactly that. Overabundance of a good thing, says the dictionary. I'll use that one.

Answer (score 1):

***Grouse*** -- [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grouse)

> (verb)  Complain about something trivial; grumble
>   *she heard him grousing about his assistant*
>
> (noun) A complaint or grumble
>   *our biggest grouse was about the noise of construction work*

See it's synonyms for more.

Comment: perhaps Gripe is also a good term, though I see it is listed as a synonym in several places.

Comment: @PV22 Yeah, and there's more where that came from. Hence the last line in my answer "see it's synonyms".